# calculating color band of resistor values and output them

Tags: c

```
I'm trying to develop a C program that calculates the resistor values by inputting the colour bands marked on the resistor.
```

Ignoring the resistor tolerance
here is my code
    output must be similar to [Calculating the resistor value with its color bands as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019527/solved-calculating-the-resistor-value-with-its-color-bands-as-input)

my codes below doesnt give me what i wanted.I want it to be able to loop back for y and no.output must be separated {3}{3}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int bandChoice;

char colorOne[10];

char colorTwo[10];
char colorThree[10];

float codeOne;

float codeTwo;

float codeThree;

float x;

void colorCodes();
void multiplier();
void color_code(char codeOne);


int main(void)

{  printf("Enter the colors of the resistor three bands, beginning with the band nearest the end. Type the colors in lowercase letters only, NO CAPS\n");
   puts(" ");

  printf("Band 1 = >");

  scanf("%s",colorOne);

  puts(" ");

  printf("Band 2 = >");

  scanf("%s",colorTwo);

  puts(" ");

  printf("Band 3 = >");

  scanf("%s",colorThree);
  puts(" ");


  printf("%f %f %f\n",colorOne,colorTwo,colorThree);

  x=(codeOne*10)+codeTwo;

  printf("Resistance value  %d");

 } 




void color_code(char codeOne )
{

  if(strcmp(colorOne, "black") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=0;
      } 
else
  if(strcmp(colorOne, "brown") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=1;
      } 
else
  if(strcmp(colorOne, "red") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=2;
      } 
else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "orange") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=3;
      }
 else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "yellow") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=4;

  } 
else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "green") == 0)
  {enter code here
    codeOne=5;
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "blue") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=6;
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "violet") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=7;
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "gray") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=8;
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorOne, "white") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=9;
      } else
  {
     printf("Invalid colors\n");
  }

}
void multiplier()
{
    if(strcmp(colorThree, "black") == 0)
    {
        codeThree=1;
    } else

    if(strcmp(colorThree, "brown") == 0)
    {
        codeThree=10;
    } else

    if(strcmp(colorThree, "red") == 0)
    {
        codeThree=pow(10.0,2);
    } else
    if (strcmp(colorThree, "orange") == 0)
    {
        codeThree=pow(10.0,3);
    } else
    if (strcmp(colorThree, "yellow") == 0)
    {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,4);

    } else
  if (strcmp(colorThree, "green") == 0)
  {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,5);
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorThree, "blue") == 0)
  {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,6);
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorThree, "violet") == 0)
  {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,7);
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorThree, "gray") == 0)
  {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,8);
      } else
  if (strcmp(colorThree, "white") == 0)
  {
    codeThree=pow(10.0,9);
      } else
      {
        printf("Invalid colors\n");
      }
}

http://imgur.com/rya9egk
```

**really appreciate if someone can help**

Comment: I would be worth your while to look at how the `enum` constants are used in [**SOLVED - Calculating the resistor value with its color bands as input**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019527/solved-calculating-the-resistor-value-with-its-color-bands-as-input). It would greatly simplify the job of associating color code with resistor values to add tot your sum use to arrive at the total resistor value. You are free to use or modify the code you find there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `color_code` function is not properly designed. You should take in as an input the color string and return the code string.

.

```
char color_code(char *colorOne )
{
  char codeOne;
  if(strcmp(colorOne, "black") == 0)
  {
    codeOne=0;
  } 
  // and so on for other colors

  // at the end
  return codeOne;
}
```

2. In the main, you need to call this `color_code` function like this, after the scanf's

.

```
codeOne = color_code(colorOne);
```

3. You also need to repeat this for the other three functions.
4. The variables `colorOne` `colorTwo` `colorthree` `codeOne` `codeTwo` `codeThree` can be made local to main, instead of global.